# How can AC propagate further than one wave length?

Tags: current

Electric field propagates at light speed. If we have a transmission line much longer than the wavelength of an AC current, how can the current ever reach the end, seeing as the electric field reverses polarity (and therefore stops propagating in one direction) cyclically?

Edit: I considered a hydrodynamic analogy, and Hearth also mentioned it, that makes it very easy to see same effect could apply to electricity. That a water circuit, with an "AC" generator that alternates between pump and suction, would be able to propagate a pressure wave through the whole circuit even if the circuit is much longer than the wavelength. If true, easy to see it would work same way with electrons.

Edit: there were comments that electric field is the surface field. but as can be easily understood from question, it is about the drift field.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the key disconnect here, the bit of information you're missing, is that *the direction of the electric field* and *the direction of propagation of the electric field* are two entirely different and unrelated quantities. In fact, in free-space waves and in certain types of waveguide, the direction of the electric field is always *perpendicular* to the direction of propagation!

So the fact that it reverses polarity doesn't stop the wave from propagating.

Making a few assumptions, you could say it *is* true that no individual electron ever makes the complete circuit, but the individual electrons are irrelevant here; it's the fields that matter.

Comment: The electric field in a wire connected to positive and negative pole is down the wire. It is electrons in wire that are electricity. So it has a lot to do with direction of propagation.

Comment: @BipedalJoe no it doesn't. "Positive" and "negative" are arbitrary; in both cases the propagation is *away* from the source.

Comment: @BipedalJoe The electric field in an ideal wire is zero, actually. In a real wire with nonzero resistivity, yes, it will be directed down the wire. But while those electrons are related to it, they're not the whole story. An electron doesn't have to make it from the source to the load to do work; it only has to move through the load. Think of it like a long pipe full of water: you push a little water at one end of the pipe, and all the water in the pipe moves, the impulse propagating at the speed of sound, until water comes out the other end. No individual molecule has to go the whole way.

Comment: @BipedalJoe One electron pushes on the next, which pushes on the next, and so on, so the electrons in the load move even if they're not the same ones that left the source.

Comment: Positive and negative aren't arbitrary. The electric field is in the direction of the current. Charged particles move along electric fields.

Comment: @BipedalJoe What hobbs is saying is that they're irrelevant to the propagation of electric field.

Comment: @Hearth A hydrodynamic analogy could work here. But for that, you have to consider that the pump reverses direction cyclically. If the water pressure wave still reaches through the pipe circuit even if it is much longer than the wave length of the pressure wave, then yes it is the same thing.

Comment: they are not irrelevant to the electric field direction

Comment: @BipedalJoe What I'm saying is that yes, the pressure wave *will* still reach through the entire pipe.

Comment: @BipedalJoe I think the disconnect here is that you're failing to understand that the *direction of the electric field* and the *direction of propagation of the electric field* are two fundamentally different and unrelated things.

Comment: @Hearth If it does, then I can more easily see that it would for electrons. Thanks for your answer on it. I'll try and see if I can read more about the effect in hydrodynamic analogy.

Comment: @Hearth they are not unrelated. the electric field propagates pretty much in the direction of itself. consider the analogy you just used of electrons pushing on electrons like water. they do not push arbitrarily, the net push is in the direction where it is easiest to push them, forward in the wire.

Comment: @BipedalJoe I'm not sure how better to explain it short of pointing you to a book on the physics of electromagnetism. Wave propagation velocity is a totally separate quantity from the motion of any individual electron. Consider also the fact that waves can propagate in a vacuum, with no electrons at all!

Comment: you just said the exact same thing applies in hydrodynamic analogy. probably easiest to point to a book about hydrodynamics then :) since it is general to any similar system.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle :D

Comment: @LuC Ah, good analogy!

Comment: @Hearth, the direction of the wave propagation and the direction of the electric field are **not** unrelated. They're very closely related but they are perpendicular to each other, according to \${\bf S}={\bf E}\times{\bf B}\$ (where \$\bf S\$ is the Poynting vector).

Comment: @ThePhoton They are very closely related in free space, but in a medium they're not. Consider a transverse-magnetic mode in a waveguide, with the wave moving down the waveguide but the electric field having components parallel to the direction of propagation.

Comment: @ThePhoton Perhaps saying "unrelated" is a bit of a stretch, but I was trying to emphasize that they are not the same thing.

Comment: @BipedalJoe, when you say "The electric field is in the direction of the current." this is not correct for transmission lines. The electric field mainly points from the transmission line to the reference conductor or return conductor; not along the line.

Comment: @Hearth, even with a TM mode, you're going to have a superposition of waves with the E field going one way and the other, so that the net effect is \$\bf S\$ pointing along the length of the line. But this is getting into more detail than OP needs at this point.

Comment: @BipedalJoe if all you're going to do everyone tells you where your misunderstanding is is to say "no it's not", why ask in the first place?

Comment: to hobbs, that is a fallacy. no one is "telling everyone", there are many people. it is a rhethorical fallacy to try and group people into "two groups". about electric field, what causes electrons to move is electric field. then there is also field from conductor and outwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in different forums numerous times. I'm sure this can be also found from the history here. People try to understand electricity as something which finally can be explained with mechanics - the first properly (Newton, about 350 years ago) formulated area of physics. Then they see something which cannot be explained properly in their self-built mechanical model. You couldn't see how in the hell an electron can ever travel from an AC generator to the load and do some work there if the line between them is longer than a wavelength?

The only explanation is that power from the generator to the load is not carried by moving electrons. What's carrying the energy is the electromagnetic wave around the conductors or in the space between the conductors in a coaxial cable. The existence of easy to move electrons in metal wires makes possible to direct the wave propagation just along the length of the transmission line, but the kinetic energy of the electrons stay low. Some wire geometries let the wave jump to the space. Antennas are specially designed for it.

When the wave meets the load at the end of the line, the electric field of the wave really can crush some electrons through the load or at least a short distance, maybe less than one micrometer before the changing field direction pulls them back. In resistors the field extends through the load and that short forth-back motion happens in whole resistor. The drifting speed of the electrons can be very slow. Substantial currents are based on the fact that there's a big number of moving electrons. Moving to both directions, even a short distance can cause in resistive material so many collisions that the material gets hot. That's used in electric heating.

Electromagnetic fields nor waves cannot be understood with mechanics. A bending wave in a mechanics have some common thing with electromagnetic wave - its transversal. But the analogy is very thin. The properties and mutual dependency of the electric and magnetic fields are totally different than  the properties and mutual dependency of tension and velocity in a material.

Comment: Not sure I saw a contradiction. @Hearth thinks a water pipe circuit with reversible pump can propagate waves throughout even if wavelength is shorter than circuit length. And as far as I can see, waves mechanically conserve momentum, in general. If you drop a stone in water, the ripple has both a crest and through. For longitudinal waves, the compression at front is followed by rarefaction at back. The wave still propagates along momentum vector, even though it has a more low pressure region behind it.

Comment: You found that a mechanical system (water pipe) exists where particles can push each other so that the effect is seen much further than at one wavelength or less away from the source. Sound in the air has the same property. Air is also material. But all these are mechanizations which do not explain electromagnetism and the wave itself has totally different structure than EM waves.

Comment: yes, and I did not see a contradiction. you wrote ”then they see some bad contradiction”, but not me in this case

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. It's now "Then they see something which cannot be explained properly in their self-built mechanical model"

Comment: but it is explained in mechanical wave systems

Comment: It became explained when someone revealed that water particles can push other water particles so that the water in the end of a tube is moved as soon as the mechanical water density wave has traveled through the pipe. It all happens inside the pipe as longitudal motion. EM waves are transversal.  In a cable there's no electric nor magnetic field which points along the cable. There's substantial current only maybe in few micrometers thick layer on the metal surface. The analogy between mechanical and EM waves is only partial. Foe example mechanical waves are unknown in the vacuum.

Comment: well, you are assuming how and when things were explained to me or if they were. the point is that there was no contradiction, and it was explained by mechanical systems. electrons move through wire because of electric field in that direction, then there is also electric field outwards.

Comment: And you may or may not assume what I am assuming of you assumptions of my assuming etc... Give a downvote for bad answers and an upvote or acceptance for a good answer. That's your best way to stop low reputation writers like me.

Comment: no because I know myself, and you are guessing from seeing a piece of text on the internet. so that's false. I don't want to stop you, I myself think mechanical basis of electromagnetism is sound, I recognize that you don't. many don't, but then again many do. the point is just that there was no contradiction. if anything my understanding of basic mechanics was a bit bad, or, just had not thought much about the scenario.

Comment: I can just engage with you as a person. I recognize that you dislike the idea of electromagnetism being mechanical. I do not. I can accept if you think I'm an idiot for that. and I can accept that you have a different opinion. and I can even accept if you think that it is wrong to call it an opinion. there is no conflict.